# Riehl's Category Theory in Context - Exercise 2.1.iv.

Tags: category-theory

I'm working through the following,

> Exercise 2.1.iv. A functor $F$ defines a *subfunctor* of $G$ if there is a natural transformation $\alpha: F \Rightarrow G$ whose components are monomorphisms. In the case of $G: C^{op} → \operatorname{Set}$, a subfunctor is given by a collection of subsets $Fc \subset Gc$ so that each $Gf : Gc \longrightarrow Gc'$ restricts to a function $Ff: Fc → Fc'$. Characterize those subsets that assemble into a subfunctor of the representable functor $C(−, c)$.

I have two questions. The first one is, when we say that a subfunctor for $G$ is given by subsets of each $Gc$, we are identifying each $Fc$ with its image via $\alpha_c$, right? So we would have uniqueness up to isomorphic objects.

Secondly, for the concrete exercise regarding $C(-,c)$, could you provide any hints on how to characterize such sets?

So far I've only noted that given $\mu: d' \rightarrow d$, we need the precomposition,

$$
\mu^{*}: f \in C(d,c) \mapsto f\mu \in C(d',c)
$$

to restrict to $Fd$ and corestrict to $Fd'$. Thus, $\mu^*(Fd) \subseteq Fd'$, and so

$$
\bigcup_{\forall \mu: \ d' \to d \\ \forall f\in Fd} f\mu \subset Fd'
$$

but I haven't got from there to any fruitful conclusions.

Comment: In the last formula in the question, underneath the big union symbol, it should not say $f:d\to c$ but rather $f\in Fd$.  With that correction, I think you've essentially finished the job. Another way to state the result is that the family $\bigcup_dF(d)$ should be closed under right-composition with arbitrary morphisms $\mu$ (whenever the composition makes sense). Such a family is called a *sieve* on $c$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass thanks a lot! If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: OK; I'll copy it into the answer box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last formula in the question, underneath the big union symbol, it should not say $f:d\to c$ but rather $f\in Fd$. With that correction, I think you've essentially finished the job. Another way to state the result is that the family $\bigcup_dF(d)$ should be closed under right-composition with arbitrary morphisms $\mu$ (whenever the composition makes sense). Such a family is called a sieve on $c$.